# How to access Azure AD Identity management from Atlassian Jira

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jira

We are actually looking to cover a solution from our jira platform.
We are using AZURE AD identitity management for handdling application catalog access.

Our goal is to automate the process of creating/adding a user into Azure AD from a Service Request issue from Jira Service Desk portal.

For exemple :
1- user submit a request from Jira Service Desk in order to have access to Confluence and RunDeck application
2 - The process should add automatically the user to the proper group in AD which then will have access to the application.

Does anyone have a solution how to approach this use case ?

Regards

Comment: Can you please clarify that you would like to achieve application access here or you want to create/update/delete the users based on JIRA service desk request? Both scenarios are possible using MS Graph. You can use MS GRaph APIs for user create/update/delete and also you can add users in different groups bases on the business requirements. But you need to write this automation or PowerShell script yourself. You can see the details about the APIs from here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0 and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/grou

Answer (score 0):

Inbound Provisioning from Atlassian Jira to Azure AD is currently not supported. You can, however, voice your interest in such a feature or support similar ones in the [Azure AD Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory?category_id=166251).

Also, you can use the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to automate user creation. Once a service request is complete, you can invoke the API for user creation from within Jira.

Comment: Hello @SCW,  if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.